# Select and update not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `viewer` with `id`, `ip`, `date_last_viewed` & `blog_id` as the columns. I'm first checking whether a particular entry having the same IP and blog_id is present or not. If yes, it updates the date. Else, it inserts a new entry.

My code is below:

```
$search_ip = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM viewer WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND blog_id= '".$b_id."' ");

if ($search_ip == false){
    $insert_ip = mysql_query("INSERT INTO viewer (ip, blog_id, date_last_viewed) VALUES ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$b_id."', NOW())");
}
else {
    $update_ip = mysql_query("UPDATE viewer SET date_last_viewed = NOW() WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND blog_id='".$b_id."' ");           
}
```

The table is not inserting anything. What am I doing wrong here? Also, as I'm new to PHP programming, could someone tell me how to modify the above code to PDO?

Comment: Well, one thing you're doing wrong is not checking that any of your queries work - add a `or die(mysql_error())` at the end, and you'll see what the error is.

Comment: mysql_query does not return boolean.

Comment: Dont use `myql_*` functions. Use their object versions instead.

Comment: Obligatory... `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used anymore. Learn about prepared statements and use `PDO` or `MySQLi`. [PHP.net Changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php)

Comment: Why it is tagged with PDO?

Answer (score 5):

You can actually do it in just one query.

MySQL has a special feature called `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which basically insert if the record does not exist or update if it already exists. One thing you need to do is to define a unique column(/s)

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Based on your statement, you need to define a unique constraint on both column,

```
ALTER TABLE viewer ADD CONSTRAINT vw_uq UNIQUE (ip, blog_id)
```

and execute this statement,

```
INSERT INTO viewer (ip, blog_id, date_last_viewed)
VALUES ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], b_id, NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date_last_viewed = NOW()
```

---

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `mysql_query` executes correctly, it wont return false. What you should do is check the number of rows it returns. You can do this using [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Also, take note of the big red warning box at the top of the `mysql_*` man pages.

Answer (score 1):

You should first add error handlers. Then move to `mysqli_` and use prepared statements.

```
$search_ip = mysql_query( "SELECT ... " ) or die( mysql_error() );

if( mysql_num_rows($search_ip) == 0 ) {
     $insert_ip = mysql_query( "INSERT ... " ) or die( mysql_error() );
}
else {
     $update_ip = mysql_query( "UPDATE ... " ) or die( mysql_error() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$search_ip` will never `== false`, because it is a reference to the result. Use `mysql_num_rows($earch_ip)` instead. Also note that `mysqli` replaces this and your code is actually deprecated

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right way to check if a query returned a value:

```
$search_ip = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM viewer WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' AND blog_id= '".$b_id."' ");

if (mysql_num_rows($search_ip)==0) {
....
}
```